# Angular if screen is above a certain breakpoint, show one div, else show another

Tags: angular, angular5

On my html I have two divs with different layouts.
One is a table, and the other one is a several divs

```
 <div class="firstView>
   <table class="table table-bordered">.....
     ..
    <tr *ngFor="let data of Data">
     <td>data.name</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </div>

 <div class="secondView">
  <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let data of Data">
     insert data here
  </div>
```

I can use show and hidden to display or hide them at certain screen sizes.
But since I load data in both of them, I think it would be best if I could have an If statement, that displays and renders firstView if screensize > 992px
and the secondView if it's less than that.

How can I have an ngIf statement with breakpoints as values?

Comment: have you tried CSS media queries?

Comment: With media queries I can only make the element display:none, but it will still have taken the data and the design , though not shown. i want to avoid that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually used an old account for the answer before, so using the chance to detail it out with the correct account here!

So if you want to save the window width to a variable, you can set up your component code like this

```
class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentWindowWidth: number;

  // ... 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  // ... 
}
```

In your markup you can then simply check as follows:

```
<div class="first" *ngIf="currentWindowWidth < 992"> 
  ... 
</div>
<div class="second" *ngIf="currentWindowWidth >= 992" > 
  ... 
</div>
```

**Edit:**

If you then want to also react to resizing you can do it as follows:

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
onResize() {
  this.currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But onInit will give the window width when it's started.
What about when I resize the window ?

Comment: Edited my original answer to include the reaction to the window's resize event!

Comment: Worked like Charm, Thanks Alot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use an *ngIf to get rid of the DOM elements themselves, you could bind `window.innerWidth` to a variable on `ngOnInit` and then use this to conditionally hide or show a container based on an *ngIf.

If you also care about resizing you can bind a host listener to the window's resize event and reassign the variable when it fires!

Comment: Thanks, but how can I bind window.innerWidth in angular5 ? The point would be that anything below 992px would show the secondView, whereas anything greater would show the firstView.
So it has to have a listener , but I'm a beginner with angular.